# PL/SQL is it possible to save a select result set into a clob

Tags: c++, oracle, plsql

Because of my C++ OCI wrapper only supports to bind Int/Double/String/Clob type of data. So I was wondering if it's possible to have my stored procedure returning a clob, which save the result set that's from a SELECT statement.

Like:

```
  FUNCTION sp(
    in_param VARCHAR2,
  ) RETURN CLOB
  IS
    my_clob  CLOB;
  BEGIN

      my_clob := SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM s WHERE s.param = in_param;
    RETURN my_clob;

  END sp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a table with a CLOB and and a VARCHAR column and this works:

```
create or replace
  FUNCTION F_LOB_TEST(in_char  VARCHAR2 ) RETURN CLOB
  IS
    my_clob  CLOB;
  BEGIN
    SELECT FIELD_CLOB 
    INTO   my_clob 
    FROM   LOB_TEST 
    WHERE  FIELD_CHAR=in_char;

    RETURN my_clob;

  END;
```

To make sure the function returns what you're expecting in PL/SQL 
you can call the above function like this:

```
select F_LOB_TEST('A') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I need the result set (all columns) to be dumped out, no matter if it's a clob column or not. SELECT INTO might just work for a column though.